# Why DateDifference returns machine number?

Tags: functions, date-and-time, finance

Is there any specific reason why `DateDifference` cannot give an exact number in this case?

```
DateDifference["Jan 2, 2013", "Jan 8, 2013", "Week"]
```

> 0.857143

Also, I'd like to know how the various `DayCountConvention` settings interact with the calculation, in particular for "Week", "Month", etc.

Comment: That will return 1, yes. But why my example will not give 6/7? DateDifference will give a machine number in general in this case, when an exact number can be easily derived.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason might be gleaned from examining the output from `TracePrint`.

```
DateDifference["Jan 2, 2013", "Jan 8, 2013", "Week"] // TracePrint (* Warning Huge Output *)
```

Somewhere close to the end of this humongous output we see the following:

```
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`n:Except[_Integer] :> N[DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`n]
6/7 /. DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`n:Except[_Integer] :> N[DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`n]
```

So it appears that *Mathematica* computes the difference using `AbsoluteTime` which gives an exact number and afterwards (if the result is not an `Integer`) takes the numerical value. Hence the result you get. To get around this one can do:

```
Rationalize[DateDifference["Jan 2, 2013", "Jan 8, 2013", "Week"]]
```

Which gives:

> `{6/7, "Week"}`

Comment: This is missing the point. I want to know why, Mathematica being what it is, does not give me 6/7 in the first place.

Comment: +1 for tracing into the function and locating the `N`. But why use `N` when the result is not an integer?

Comment: @asterix314. That I cannot explain. There's no clue as to why in that huge `TracePrint` output either.

Comment: @asterix314 I think as users we cannot really answer the "why" question in a satisfactory way. RunnyKine's response shows why the behavior arises, but if you don't like it or want someone to justify it to you, I think you'll have to raise it with support or file it as a bug.